# How to use NavigationController by taping on CollectionViewCell which in TableViewCell

Tags: swift

I want to pushViewController and show detail about that cell!

Swift5

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self
    }    
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return ViewController.typeOfDishes.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return ViewController.typeOfDishes[section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell") as! MyTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}





import UIKit

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        myCollectionView.delegate = self
        myCollectionView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension MyTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return ViewController.dishesCountByArray[ViewController.indexOfTableView!]
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
////////////There I want to do PushViewController Action        
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = self.myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

I want to normally pu​sh when user taps on collection view cell

Answer (score 0):

Inside here Add a delegate

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   weak var delegate:ViewController?
   .....
}
```

Then set it here

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = self.myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell") as! MyTableViewCell
   cell.delegate = self
   return cell
}
```

Now you can push here

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
   let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondID") as! SecondViewController  
   self.delegate?.navigationController?.push////
}
```

Comment: When i select a cell,i see black screen:
let vc = SecondViewController()
        self.delegate?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

Comment: it appears secondVc is in storyboard , so load it as in edit after you set a storyboard identifier `SecondID` to it

Comment: By storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)

Comment: By this way?    If yes, there is no storyboard

Comment: how do you create secondVC ? if programmatically then change it's view's background inside viewDidLoad

Comment: no, I have created it in the storyboard, get ID secondVC

Comment: i have created secondVC as ViewController in storyboard, get him class and ID, it had yellow background, but i see blackscreen

Comment: ok try with `let vc = UIViewController() ; vc.view.bacgroundColor = .red` and see if works then you have a configuration problem

Comment: Sorry, but can i send it you, to see it?